# pg_dump ignores postgis functions and types

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pg-dump

I'm trying to dump the public schema of a database that contains postgis functions and types.  The reason why is beyond the question - would be too long to explain why I need to do this.

Anyhow, when I do

```
pg_dump -d <db> -h  <host>  -U <user> -n public -Fp > public.sql
```

the file is essentially empty.  I checked (tried different servers too) and all functions and types are in there in public scheams.  I'm using the right user, etc..  I even tried to create my own function in there and this one *only* ended up in the output file

Anyone has a clue why ?

thanks.

Comment: They're created by an extension, right? I doubt you can dump them.

Answer (score 3):

Extensions are dumped "by reference" not by listing all of their components.

The creation of the individual components can be found in the installation script.

```
vi `pg_config --sharedir`/extension/postgis--3.1.1.sql
```

But you would have to tweak that to get the proper version.

Comment: ok. I did not know this.
Thanks for the information